# Dynamically load CSS stylesheet in <link> tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to dynamically load CSS links in `<link>` tag with JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" class="js-load-css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>I am formatted with a linked style sheet</h1>
<p>Me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Two questions here:

1) Is having empty `href` attribute with `<link>` Ok?

2) Is there any other tag that would better suite in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is having empty href attribute with  Ok?

It is a relative URL that resolves to the current URL, which is an HTML document, which is not a stylesheet. So no.

> Is there any other tag that would better suite in this situation?

No. Append a new `<link>` element to `document.head` when your CSS wants to load the CSS. There is no need for a placeholder element at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Javascript to add a new stylesheet `<link>` tag to the `document.head`.

```
var stylesheet = document.createElement("link");
stylesheet.rel = "stylesheet";
stylesheet.type = "text/css";
stylesheet.href = "your_file.css";

document.head.appendChild(stylesheet);
```